# ExoPlayer doesn't see local files

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer

For one week I try to play a local mp4 file in my Jetpack Compose app. I have scanned all the Internet and tried a good deal of code snippets. A very big problem with it is that almost all of them are marked now as deprecated ones.

I have tried this:

```
var file = File(context.filesDir.getAbsolutePath(), "1.MP4")
val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(
    context,
    DefaultDataSource.Factory(context)
)

val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(file.absolutePath))

val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
    setMediaSource(mediaSource)
    prepare()
    play()
  }
```

And this:

```
val uri = RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.video3)
val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri)
val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
    setMediaItem(mediaItem)
    prepare()
    play()
}
```

I have tried it for several mp4 and one mp3. I copied the files to assets, res/raw and data/data//files folders. I have tried remote files, but it appeared that my emulator had no internet connection so I left this way.

When I check the file's existence I see it exists.

```
var file = File(context.filesDir.getAbsolutePath(), "1.MP4")
if (file.exists())
// true
```

But ExoPlayer doesn't see it. When I set in my log

```
exoPlayer.videoSize.width.toString()
```

it gets 0.

I have no idea how to solve my problem. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange but I have just found the solution!

The clue is that ExoPlayer doesn't show itself. So we are to write something like this:

```
AndroidView(
    factory = {
        PlayerView(it).apply {
            player = exoPlayer
        }
    },
)
```